# jQuery Mobile on landscape portrait change re-render page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating an app in jQuery Mobile based on wordpress with a child theme for twenty twelve. Probably the CSS could be made better. The app loads fine and is without zoom and no scrolling with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

But when changing orientation on an iPhone from **landscape to portrait** I'm getting a wider screen than the actual page and the scroll shows up in the middle when there is an input-field in a form on the page. **however when choosing (focus-ing) on a form input field the page re-renders and the width is correct with no scroll**. I've used some responsive css present like @media only screen and (max-width:..

So is there a good way of doing this?

```
//This one triggers on orientation change
jQuery( window ).on('orientationchange', function( event ) { 
  if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
    // Rerender as if an input field is focused.. 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution. Better ofcourse is to prevent it to build some good CSS from the ground up, but if using twenty twelve as a parent theme in wordpress - this code might come handy.

```
jQuery( window ).on('orientationchange', function( event ) { 
    if(event.orientation == 'portrait'){
        jQuery('body').fadeOut(300, function(){ 
            jQuery('body').fadeIn(300);
        });
    }
});
```