# jQuery Mobile Orientation Change re-render without losing page data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Almost exactly similar to the question posted here: [jQuery Mobile on landscape portrait change re-render page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998991/jquery-mobile-on-landscape-portrait-change-re-render-page)

Whenever I rotate the phone, the side menu on the page gets all screwy because of a large white block that gets added to the `ui-content` section of the page.

If I add the following:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  $.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
    allowSamePageTransition: true,
    transition: 'none',
    reloadPage: true
  });
});
```

... then any static page will work just fine.

However, many of our pages have results from Web Service calls and those go *poof* if I use the solution listed on that other question.

So ... how do I do this for pages with web service data?  I've tried `page.trigger("create")` as well but that didn't seem to work either.

jQuery Mobile v. 1.4.2
PhoneGap Cordova v. 3.4

Page Layout:

```
<div data-role="header" id="appheader" data-id="head" data-add-back-btn="false" data-position="fixed">
            <a class="icononly" style="display: none;" data-icon="fi-back" onclick="$.mobile.back();"></a>  
            <h1 style="position: relative; text-align: center; height: 100%;">
                <div class="ui-page-title-current" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">Welcome</div>
            </h1>
            <a class="icononly" data-icon="fi-menu" id="menuBtn" href="#mainNav"></a>
        </div>  
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="fi" data-ajax="false" id="welcome">
            <div class="ui-page-title">Welcome</div>
            <div class="ui-content" role="main">
                <div id="welcomeLogo">
                    <center><img src="images/welcome-logo.png" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" /></center>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div style="clear:both" class="welcome-links">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="33%" style="text-align:center"><a class="welcome-btn-myagency" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('Agent');">My Agency</a></td>
                            <th width="33%"><a class="welcome-btn-viewpolicy" href="#" onclick="global.IdCardListManager.ClearList();global.ViewSavedIdCards=false;VerifyLoginAndNavigate('MyPolicy');">View My Policy</a></th>
                            <th width="33%"><a class="welcome-btn-viewidcards" href="#" onclick="global.IdCardListManager.ClearList();global.ViewSavedIdCards=true;phsNavigateTo('IdCards');">View Auto ID Cards</a></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="33%"><a class="welcome-btn-paymybill" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('PayYourBill');">Pay My Bill</a></th>                                
                            <td width="33%" style="text-align:center"><a class="welcome-btn-claimscenter" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('ClaimCenter');">Claim Center</a></td>
                            <td width="33%" style="text-align:center"><a class="welcome-btn-roadside" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('RoadSideAccidentHelp');">Roadside/Accident Assistance</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="panel-content" style="display:none">
            <div id="navwrap">
                <div data-role="panel" data-position="right" id="mainNav" data-display="push" class="mainNav">
                    <div data-role="content">
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false">
                            <li style="display:inline-block;float:left;width:50%"><a class="ui-icon-fi-home" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('Home', '', 'reverse');">Home</a></li>
                            <li style="display:inline-block"><a id="menuLogin" class="ui-icon-fi-login" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('Login');">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false">
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-myagent" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('Agent');">My Agency</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-mypolicy" href="#" onclick="global.IdCardListManager.ClearList();global.ViewSavedIdCards=false;VerifyLoginAndNavigate('MyPolicy');">View My Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-autoidcards" href="#" onclick="global.IdCardListManager.ClearList();global.ViewSavedIdCards=true;phsNavigateTo('IdCards');">View Auto ID Cards</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-paybill" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('PayYourBill');">Pay My Bill</a></li>                    
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-claimscenter" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('ClaimCenter');">Claims Center</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-roadside" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('RoadSideAccidentHelp');">Roadside/Accident Assistance</a></li>                    
                        </ul>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false">
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-contact" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('Contact');">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-agencylocator" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('AgencyLocator');">Agency Locator</a></li>                  
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-about" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('AboutUs');">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a class="ui-icon-fi-terms" href="#" onclick="phsNavigateTo('TermsOfUse', '', '' , 'Y');">Terms of Use</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The contents of the #navwrap div are programmatically added to each .ui-page-active via javascript.

Here is what happens the before/after pictures:[image: Page is loaded as Portrait just fine]

[image: but when rotated to Landscape, gets messed up]

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: What creates the large white block that gets added to the ui-content. Is it natural or added dynamically. If its dynamic then take it out if its in the way. What creates the pages with web service data. Can you add the code to the question. Maybe its something you can RE-request from the web again on orientation change.  Put some code to see.

Comment: Sorry ... thought I had put the versions in there but must have forgot.  *added*    

As far as what creates the "white block" ... it's nothing in my code.  I'll include the code of the page so you can see what's there.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I thought the following fixed it, but it only made a difference on pages where the content didn't require scrolling.  As soon as you start scrolling the content area, an unidentified white box starts scrolling up from the bottom of the screen again, swallowing anything in its path :(

Researching this farther, I found an answer here ... https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-white-area-when-changing-orientation

... from that page ...

> This is a pretty common issue. The way you get around it is to set all your page heights to 100%.
> Now keep in mind, you have to do this on all containers. Something
> like:
>
> body { height: 100%;}
>
> myPage { height: 100%; }
>
> myPage .content { height: 100%;}

What I did was put height:100% on body, .ui-page and .ui-content and that seemed to work.